# Postman works, but the "Code snippet" generated no. cURL

Tags: rest, curl, post, postman

From my computer the query via postman to my endpoint works, it returns the expected result.
but the code generated by "code snippet" does not work, what could be the cause ?

--That code doesnt work. But in postman yes (same laptop)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://service' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: myKey' \
--header 'Content-Type: audio/mpeg' \
--data-binary '@/path/audio_test.mp3'
```

Error: `curl: (28) Failed to connect to <service> port 443: Timed out`

To check that it is not a problem with my end, I tried another service that works in postman and the code generated by postman through "code snippet" works as well.

-- That works in postman and in my consol --

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://´service' \
--header 'Key: myKey' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"text":"myText",
"language": "en"
}
'
```

its return the expected result

Does anyone have any idea where I could look?  Thanks

Comment: what happens if you telnet the URL on port 443 on the same context you're runnign the curl for request number 1?

Comment: Hi @bitoiu what exactly do you mean with "telnet the URL on port 443" ? Do you mean that ? 'https://service:443' in the Curl query ?

Comment: Well, the error you're receiving is a connection error, not an API error. So I'm trying to understand if your console, wherever you're calling postman can talk to that service. For that you can use telnet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/telnet

Comment: hi  @bitoiu thank you very much for your help, the port is close. telnet my_service 443 show me the message that the connection fail

Comment: Hi @bitoiu ... beginner error.. I was working with the vpn  from my company active as normaly when I need to thest the endpoints. I just tried it without vpn and worked, pleas add the answer and I will validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to  port 443: Timed out

This will likely be a connection error either due to the client context (application/terminal) or the client host (the device itself). I assume the second request doesn't try to hit the same location or it was ran from another context.

Check your connection first and then troubleshoot from your way up. To do so, in the **same exact** place you're running your `curl` run the following:

`telnet service 443`

Where `service` is the endpoint you are using in the request. If that still gives the same error then the issue is down to a networking problem. Check from other clients, check VPNs or other applications that could be causing the blockage.